# Bootstrap Carousel children elements won't display responsive margin or padding

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, spacing

I want to get the carousel-caption element within Bootstrap's carousel to allow repositioning of the elements therein at the standard Bootstrap breakpoints (`sm`, `md`, `lg`, `xl`).

Currently no matter what i do when adding a class (for example, `pb-lg-5`) to either the carousel-caption element or any of its children (`<h2>` or `<p>` elements for example), only one value will be used. Specifying padding across all four breakpoints will not work. If i set, say, padding for an `<h2>` element as "pb-sm-2 pb-md-4 pb-lg-5 pb-xl-1", only one value will function and none of the others will display correctly.

Below is my working example.

http://codepen.io/stripeycat/pen/WavdXQ

```
<div class="carousel-caption text-left">
   <div>
      <h2 class="mb-sm-1 mb-md-4 mb-lg-3 mb-xl-5">Headline Text</h2>
      <p>Paragraph Text</p>
   <div>
</div>
```

Is this an issue cause by positioning within the carousel? Or am I missing something completely?

Comment: why not tp add snippet https://codepen.io  ?

Comment: Ok, so i dont really understand how this codepen works but i have added the HTML and the CSS for this to that website here: https://codepen.io/stripeycat/pen/WavdXQ

Comment: 1) go to settings in top right corner, add bootstrap js and css 2) title codepen 3) add comments like // this doesn't work? I have expected ...

Comment: Sure, i have implemented these steps now. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1) why `pb-xl-1` in `pb-sm-2 pb-md-4 pb-lg-5 pb-xl-1` ? it seems not logical "for most wide screen - smallest padding"; next your sample the same unclear "mb-sm-1 mb-md-4 **mb-lg-3** mb-xl-5", why not `mb-md-3 mb-lg-4`?

2) only one padding value from the sequence should be used, it is by design, which one depends on the screen size; this is very clear for natural growing sequences like `pb-sm-2 pb-md-3 pb-lg-4 pb-xl-5` -https://codepen.io/rpokrovskij/pen/NOqzEX  padding rizes with each screen resizing.

3) as I understand your case - here is nothing specific to carousel

Comment: the spacing is not consistent as i will use different images across four different breakpoints. this means it will be quite different on sm, md, lg and xl (it does not grow as the size increases). the problem i have is that i need to set a high value for the xl to push the carousel-caption high for the largest (the widescreen) breakpoint, but i want to use much less padding for the smallest (sm) otherwise the caption is jammed all the way up the top of the carousel on mobile devices.

Comment: You wrote" "i need to set a high value for the xl..  but i want to use much less padding for the smallest (sm)". My codepen works exactly as you say, isn't it?

Comment: If not - add your images to your codepen' caroiusel to demonstrate those jams. Copdepen should be adequate to the question.

Comment: i think i need to add the actual carousel here to give a better indication of the behaviour i'm seeing, i don't think that what i've generated here is providing the explanation i need.

Answer (score 0):

I have isolated the problem; as I wrote additional Bootstrap-style Spacing classes into my additional custom CSS document, i believe that these were not being referenced correctly in relation to the cascade.

On having rewritten these directly into the bootstrap stylesheet (following the exact form of the existing CSS), the browser is now correctly attracting my additional styles.